# Strange escaping in Django

Tags: python, django

Django seems to be behaving oddly with escaping my JSON.

When I use the admin interface to enter JSON it works fine and the JSON is stored unescaped in the database.

However when I use the model interface it escapes it, which makes it look nasty...

I'm using the following code:

```
kwargs['instance'].attributes = kwargs['instance'].module.module.data
```

module.module.data currently = {"code":"","type":""}

but when it's inserted into the database it looks like this: "{\"code\": \"\", \"type\": \"\"}"

However if I use the django admin interface, it's fine. It ends up in the database exactly as I entered it.

I can't for the life of me figure out why. I've spent a frustrating couple of hours trying all sorts of things.

Answer (score 0):

My issue was that I needed to load the JSON into a python data structure with json.loads and then this was entered into the database correctly!